# Parse.com callback is exist?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, callback

Suppose, we have two clients connected to the server. And one that clients updates the object on the server. Is there a way to the second client was notified about this? That is, whether there is a possibility to Parse send call back to the certain client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Push Notification. indeed Notifications are design to send alert and badges to client side. we have 2 type of notification in iOS.But in your case Push-notification will work perfects. check these video you may understand what i mean to say

[Apple Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)

Comment: Thank you. I know about it, but for my targets performance of this 
approach is not enough. I mean some of http sessions callbacks...

Comment: so please share you need here either push notification is enough for any Solution @alex sed please write you approach or what you want to achieve

Comment: I'm writing a game, and it need more quick data sharing that two step within push notifications approach. Fortunately, just now I found that Apple game centre allow create multiplayer games...